# How to reference a file in a GitHub issue?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

In **GitHub** issues, can I reference a file in the repository directly in the issue and have it auto-link?

Comment: Use `../blob/master`. E.g.: `[/src/file.js](../blob/master/src/file.js)`

Comment: @laggingreflex comment must be an accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: or use ../tree/master. E.g.: [/src/file.js](../tree/master/src/file.js)

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It's clearly about a "tool primarily used for programming"

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You cannot auto-link to a file, only [commits and issues](//help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls).

Side note, it is better to use a hash when linking to make it “future proof”.
Example:

```
http://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3244d8b/MANIFESTO
```

Comment: What you can do, though, is add `#l38` in the end to link directly to a line: `https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3244d8b/MANIFESTO#l28`

Comment: Apparently, it's important to use a capital L, so: `#L38`.

Comment: Or even simpler - while browsing repo, just click selected line number on the left and copy URL :)

Comment: @KrzysztofGrzybek for some reason the left-hand-side line links can't be copied (in my browser at least, ~2021)

Comment: @usretc that's weird.. I'm still able to do this (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: You can also copy multiple lines by holding Shift. This results in `#Ln-Lm` at the end of the URL

Comment: @usretc You click the line number, which is an anchor link `...MANIFESTO#L4` and notice the URL in your browser has changed. Copy that.

There's also a meatball menu that appears when you click the line, which when clicked pops up a tooltip/balloon with various copy options, "Copy Line" and "Copy Permalink", amongst other useful options like "Blame" and "Reference in New Issue" which is a great way to create an Issue with the spirit of this question in mind.